# Trisecting an angle!

Tags: geometry

I have read most of the literature, including your various answers, 
that "insist" that an angle cannot be trisected. Nevertheless, I 
believe I have the solution to this age-old problem. It seems to work 
on any angle except a right angle. It does not involve any of the 
problems I've seen described in the literature and is in strict 
compliance with the use of only a straightedge and a compass. I 
developed the solution myself.
I will provide my construction without benefit of a diagram. If you follow the steps 
carefully, you will be able to construct the diagram without much difficulty. Although this works on any angle except a straight angle, I suggest for STEP 1 you use an angle of about 70 to 90 degrees and for STEP 2 a circle with radius of about 2 inches:

STEP 1: Draw angle BAC.

STEP 2: From point A, draw circle to intersect line BA at point D 
           and line CA at point E.

STEP 3: Extend line BDA until it intersects circle at point F.

STEP 4: Extend line CEA until it intersects circle at point G.

STEP 5: Bisect arc DE at point H.

STEP 6: Draw lines GD and FH until they intersect at point I.

STEP 7: Draw lines FE and GH until they intersect at point J.

STEP 8: Draw lines AI and AJ.

STEP 9: Angle BAI = angle IAJ = angle JAC!?!(by measuring with a compass)
Do you find any hole or flaw?

Comment: Where is your PROOF that $\angle BAI=\angle IAJ$?

Comment: @Martigan I have done measurements using a protractor.

Comment: Measurement is no proof. You need to build a proof with equalities of angles etc. It may very well that your process gives three angles, two of which are equals (trivially so) and very close to the third, so much you won't see the difference with a simple measurement.

Comment: "Do you find any hole or flaw in the proof?": how could we, there is no proof !

Comment: @ Navneet Kumar :They are many known methods to trisect an angle with accuracy as good as we want (but not exact in mathematical sens). They are also known methods which are exact, but doesn't comply the rules of trisection defined by the ancient Greeks : these methods are called  Neusis. If you do a measurement with compas or other tool for proving your result, this is a neusis proof which is rejected as not fulfilling the rules. It is smart and enterprising to study this problem, but before all, learn the rules and what was already done. https://fr.scribd.com/document/14557717/Trisection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the flaw in your proof is that you have omitted the proof. Or put more precisely you've omitted the proof that $\angle BAI=\angle IAJ =\angle JAC$. In fact they are not all the same. They may be approximately the same, but nevertheless not the same. That's why you may measure the same value.

It's quite clear that $\angle BAI=\angle JAC$ by symmetry however.

In fact it's not just that nobody haven't been able to trisect an angle in general using these methods in all these years. During this time there have come up with proofs that it is impossible to do so. This means that when you think you've come up with a solution one can be quite certain that you've done some mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use empirical methods (measurement) to test an algorithm at least use tools which by themselves won't introduce errors of at least 1% regardless of how careful you are. With Geogebra or some other computer tool you'd start getting somewhere.

Regardless. If you plug in your algorithm into Geogebra you see that you're getting decent approximations of a trisection but still several degrees off. See this example image

[image]

Or play around with this application by dragging B and C. https://www.geogebra.org/m/UbR7scEC

For 180 degree angles you see the deviation from a true trisection is about 10 degrees but for smaller angles it might be somewhat useful in say woodworking in case you've misplaced your protractor.

Answer (score 2):

There are unnecessary elements in your "proof": the points $B, C$ play no role and half of the figure is enough (you can drop $E$).

[image]

Now WLOG let us use the unit circle and

$$A=(0,0),D=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta),F=(-\cos\theta,-\sin\theta),G=(-\cos\theta,\sin\theta), H=(1,0).$$

Then $I$ is the intersection of $GD$ and $FH$, which is found to be $(2+\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and the would-be third angle is given by

$$\theta^*=\arctan\frac{\sin\theta}{2+\cos\theta}.$$

The angle is everywhere under-estimated, but the error may remain graphically invisible up to $\dfrac\pi4$ or so ($2.4\%$ drop).

[image]

As said by @skying, it is not possible to trisect the angle with straightedge  and compass, full stop.

Comment: Does the trigonometric relation apply to the full angle or half of it?  I think the latter, so for instance the point you plot for $\pi /4$ radians actualky corresponds to an input angle of $\pi /2$ radians.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: my angle is $HAD$, there is no "full angle" in the half figure.

Comment: ok now I see.  This led me to find a correction in my own answer, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If my interpretation is correct, then if we start with an angle $\theta$ then the central " third" $\phi$ of the angle satisfies:

$\tan({\phi}/2)={\sin({\theta}/2)}/{(2+\cos({\theta}/2))}$

Put in a right angle for $\theta$ and the constructed value of $\phi$ is $29.28$ degrees (four significant digits).  If you modify the method for obtuse angles by trisectng the supplement and then subtracting from $60°$, you can trisect any angle form zero to a straight angle with an error less than three-fourths of a degree in the central third (and half that, in the opposite direction, for each of the other two pieces).  That would indeed be difficult to pick up with typical measurement methods.